# Поиск максимально похожей строки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с двумя колонками **id** и **hash**
В столбце **hash** содержатся **хеши картинок**, созданные по специальному алгоритму.
Нужно найти максимально похожие строки и отсортировать их по релевантности (с минимальным количеством отличий). 
И вывести id 10-ти ближайших по релевантности хешей.

Пример значения (одна строка):

```
00-9 01-2 023 037 046 05-5 06-10 072 083 094 105 11-4 12-2 134 14-11 15-21 
16-12 17-5 18-4 19-3 205 21-13 22-3 23-4 24-8 25-32 26-4 27-2 28-3 29-9 30-3 
31-4 32-8 33-5 34-26 35-66 364 373 382 39-28 40-4 413 423 43-3 44-4 454 464 
472 48-8 49-23 502 51-2 524 53-12 543 55-2 56-3 57-30 58-13 59-5 604 61-9 
62-5 63-5 643 65-18 66-6 67-10 68-5 69-4 70-3 71-5 72-6 73-15 742 75-8 763 
773 783 793 802 81-4 823 83-2 84-11 853 863 873 88-2 893 90-18 915 92-3 933 
94-3 95-5 962 973 983 993 k05 k12 k2-6 k3-2 k43 k52 k6-12 k7-7 k8-28 k9-8 l03 
l1-2 l2-3 l32 l4-3 l5-2 l6-3 l72 l8-12 l9-6 m0-3 m1-2 m22 m3-3 m42 m5-2 m6-3 
m7-7 m83 m94 n0-2 n12 n23 n3-2 n4-2 n52 n6-7 n74 n85 n94 o02 o12 o2-4 o33 o42 
o55 o64 o73 o82 o9-3 p03 p13 p2-3 p33 p43 p56 p64 p7-4 p84 p96
```

Пробовал через FULLTEXT, но независимо от значения ключа выдается один и тот же список id.

Какие могут быть еще способы?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [Расстояние Левенштейна в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php):

> В простейшей форме функция принимает в качестве аргументов две строки
>   и возвращает минимальное количество вставок, замен и удалений символов,  необходимое для преобразования str1 в str2.

**UPD**

**Реализация**

```
define('TOP', 3);        // кол-во максимально "похожих" хешей    
define('COUNT_HASH', 5); // кол-во хешей (размер входных данных)

/**
 * Генератор тестовых данных
 * @param $count
 * @return Generator
 */
function makeTestData($count)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        yield [$i, md5($i)]; // md5 -- как пример хеш-функции
    }
};


/*
 * Генерация комбинаторных сочетаний
 * (реалиазция взята из http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#PHP)
 */
function makeCombinations($set = [], $size = 0)
{
    if ($size == 0) {
        return [[]];
    }
    if ($set == []) {
        return [];
    }

    $prefix = [array_shift($set)];
    $result = [];
    foreach (makeCombinations($set, $size-1) as $suffix) {
        $result[] = array_merge($prefix, $suffix);
    }
    foreach (makeCombinations($set, $size) as $next) {
        $result[] = $next;
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Функция, используемая для оценки "похожести" набора хешей
 *
 * @param $input
 * @return number
 */
function evaluate($input)
{
    $calculate = function () use ($input) {
        foreach (makeCombinations($input, 2) as $item) {
            $first = $item[0][1];
            $second = $item[1][1];
            yield levenshtein($first, $second);
        }
    };
    return array_sum(iterator_to_array($calculate()));
}


$testData = iterator_to_array(makeTestData(COUNT_HASH));
$combinations = makeCombinations($testData, TOP);


// оценим каждую комбинацию
$result = [];
for ($index = 0; $index < count($combinations); $index++) {
    $result[] = [$index, evaluate($combinations[$index])];
}

// отсортируем комбинации по оценке
usort($result, function ($first, $second) {
    return $first[1] - $second[1];
});


$index = $result[0][0]; // индекс комбинации
$result = $combinations[$index]; // значение комбинации
```

**Результат**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 1
      1 => string 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b' (length=32)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 3
      1 => string 'eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3' (length=32)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 5
      1 => string 'e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5' (length=32)
```

**Комметарий**

- вместо Левенштейна можно использовать любую другую [подобную](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php) функцию
- остается открытым вопрос, что подразумевается под
  "***похожестью***" хешей

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.